# Check if query exsists and get results (1 Query)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to check if a value exists; the issue is that I don't want to run the query twice for speed issues. Does anyone know how to get the results of this query without running it twice? See example below.

```
if exists(select [row1],[row2] from [tablename] where [row2] = 'myvariable')

BEGIN
    PRINT 'EXISTS'
    // -- GET VALUE OF ROW 2 without running another query
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'DOES NOT EXIST' 
END
```

Comment: Does row really mean row shouldn't that be column? The whole question seems to mix those concepts up.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility: use a temp table.

```
SELECT  [row1]
      , [row2]
INTO    #tmp
FROM    [tablename]
WHERE   [row2] = 'myvariable'


IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    #tmp )
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'EXISTS'
        SELECT  row2
        FROM    #tmp t
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'DOES NOT EXIST' 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

For speed, and to avoid querying the same data twice, try this.  It only returns one row on your logical check and you don't have to pull data from the table.  In this case I returned 'whatever' when the column, [row2] ='myvariable'

```
    if exists(select top 1 'whatever' from [tablename] where [row2] = 'myvariable')

    BEGIN
        PRINT 'EXISTS'
        // -- GET VALUE OF ROW 2 without running another query
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'DOES NOT EXIST' 
    END
```

Comment: You could also go with `SELECT 1 FROM...`